# How to install Wordpress from hosting service with mysql database from Compute Engine GCP?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, wordpress, google-compute-engine

I own a wordpress website (website.com) that running well with hosting service (cpanel). So i want to create a new subdomain (new.website.com) and install wordpress in there but for the database i want to use Compute Engine from Google Cloud Platform.

I already install mysql on the CE and running perfectly, but unfortunately i couldn't connect it to my hosting service to install wordpress.

how can i do this?

what i already tried:

create mysql on CE (running with ssh)
create database, create user(connect to web ip), and password
changing the my.cnf (change the bind-address to 0.0.0.0)
setting up wp-config installation on file manager on my hosting service, such as: database_name,user,password, and host
connect the database from CE to mysql client (mysql workbench)
make sure the port open: 3306
output: "error establishing a database connection" when i try new.website.com

potentially to be the problem:

the mysql, i couldn't retrieve the database ip, cs when i run "mysql> status" it would return: connection: Localhost via UNIX socket
the wp-config setup, do i need to change the db_host? i thought it should be the database ip, but i couldn't get the ip.
cheers from indonesia.

Answer (score 0):

**To solve your issue** you should follow steps below:

1. Be sure that your instance has a static external IP or change it to static. By default VM instances has [ephemeral external IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses#ephemeraladdress) which could be changed and cause an issue with connection to the database. To do it follow the documentation [Reserving a new static external IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#reserve_new_static) and [Changing or assigning an external IP address to an existing instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#IP_assign).
2. Add network tag `mysql-server` (or any other) to use it at the next step while creating a firewall rule by following the documentation [Adding tags to an existing VM](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags#adding_new_tags_to_vm_instances)
3. Create a new firewall rule to allow traffic from your hosting to the GCE VM instance by following the documentation [Creating firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#console). Use your network tag as a `Target tags`, IP of the existing hosting as a `Source IP ranges` and open only TCP port 3306 to make your setup more secure.
4. Use reserved at step 1 static external IP of your VM instance as `'DB_HOST'` instead of `'localhost'` because MySQL database located on the different server.

In case you need to connect to the MySQL database from your hosting using command line follow the documentation [4.2.4 Connecting to the MySQL Server Using Command Options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connecting.html) and use reserved at step 1 static external IP. You can find some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872543).